# Biblical personality prepared wicks of Menorah

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach

Is there a source that mentions a person from Nach who prepared the wicks of the Menorah? I thought it was Elkana but can’t find a source to say it was him. Could it be a different person?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be thinking of Megillah 14a:

> ודבורה אשה נביאה אשת לפידות (שופטים ד:ד) מאי אשת לפידות שהיתה עושה פתילות למקדש
>   "And Devorah was a prophetess, the wife of *Lapidot*" (Judges 4:4). What is "the wife of *Lapidot*"? That she would make wicks for the Temple